# Is the normal union/find algorithm thread safe without any extra work?

Tags: algorithm, multithreading, data-structures, lock-free

The standard [union/find or Disjoint-set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure) data structure has very good running times (effectively `O(1)`) for single threaded cases. However what is it's validity/performance under multi-threaded cases? I *think* that it is totally valid even without locking or any atomic operations aside from atomic pointer sized writes.

Does anyone see any problems with the following logic?

> First I will assume that pointer sized writes are atomic. From that, it's not hard to argue that you can safely run the `find` function in several threads as the only updates that will occur are all sets to the same value. If you allow the `find` function to return the answer that was true when it was called (as opposed to when it returned) it's not hard to argue that many `find`s and a single `union` can be run at the same time; the argument for the `find`s doesn't change and the `union` only updates roots and the `find`s never update roots.
>
> As for the remaining case (several `union`s), I think that works as well but I'm not so sure of it.

BTW: I'm not requiring that the solution be just as efficient as the single threaded version. (In order to avoid locks/atomic, I'm also willing to discard globally coherent state.)

---

*edit:* taking another look, the many-union cases doesn't work because if the side that is not the new root is unioned with something else (also not as a root) then you could cut it off of other side of the second union.

```
A = find(a)  // union 1
B = find(b)  // union 1
----
X = find(x)  //   union 2 (x == a) -> (X == A) -> (X.par aliases A.par)
Y = find(y)  //   union 2
X.par = Y    //   union 2
----
A.par = B    // union 1
```

this can be sidestepped with a [CAS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compare-and-swap):

```
while(!CAS(A == A.par, B)) A = find(A);
```

Comment: I think even with the CAS, two parallel attempts to union A and B might create a cycle between A and B.

Answer (score 2):

The type of synchronization which you can use for this structure is similar with the [Readers-writers problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Readers-writers_problem). The performance will depend on how many unions will be executed because then the find operation will be stopped.

I'm not sure that you can run many finds and a single union in the same time because the last case from an union operation is not atomic.

Comment: If the non atomic union thing you are referring to is the rank part, yeah, you've got me there. But if you drop that I don't think you will loose much.

Comment: See edit. OTOH this issue is not a problem with the 1-union/many-find case as find will never find something that isn't a parent in the current group and any assignment is valid as long as the assigned value is a parent in the current group.

Comment: Suppose you have 2 elements in the same set and you do finds on them.If at the second find the parent is changed right before reaching the parent the result can be messed.So you will need to lock the sets when you are doing union.This example can be solved in another way but I don't find one better.

Comment: I don't agree: at the start of a find, every node in the tree points to something closer to the root. During the update step, the pointer is updated from something valid to something else that is also valid. (BTW I'm assuming using NULL to denote the root) A find/union would work almost the same.

Answer (score 0):

A little late but for future reference. With atomic operations, you can build a disjoint set data structure. The invariant is that each set is represented by its smallest member, which allows avoiding loops due to race conditions.

```
// atomic_compare_and_exchange(unsigned int *data, unsigned int new_value, unsigned int comparator)


// "The result used to be the root of v once"
static unsigned int GetSet(volatile unsigned int *H_RESTRICT set, const unsigned int v)
{
  unsigned int next;
  unsigned int root = v;
  unsigned int prev = v;

  while (root != (next = set[root]))
  {
    /* Update set[prev] to point to next instead of root.
      * If it was updated by some other thread in the meantime, or if this
      * is the first step (where set[prev]==next, not root), ignore. */
    atomic_compare_and_exchange(set + prev, next, root);

    prev = root;
    root = next;
  }

  /* Update the path to the root */

  return root;
}

// FALSE == "They used not to be in the same set"
// TRUE == "They are in the same set, and will be forever"
static HBOOL IsInSameSet(volatile unsigned int *H_RESTRICT set, unsigned int v1, unsigned int v2)
{
  do
  {
    v1 = GetSet(set, v1);
    v2 = GetSet(set, v2);
  } while (set[v1] != v1 || set[v2] != v2);

  return v1 == v2;
}

static void Union(volatile unsigned int *H_RESTRICT set, unsigned int v1, unsigned int v2)
{
  unsigned int result;

  do
  {
    v1 = GetSet(set, v1);
    v2 = GetSet(set, v2);
    if (v1 == v2)
    {
      /* Already same set. This cannot be changed by a parallel operation. */
      break;
    }
    if (v1 < v2)
    {
      /* Make sure we connect the larger to the smaller set. This also avoids
       * cyclic reconnections in case of race conditions. */
      unsigned int tmp = v1;
      v1 = v2;
      v2 = tmp;
    }

    /* Make v1 point to v2 */
    result = atomic_compare_and_exchange(set + v1, v2, v1);
  } while (result != v1);
}
```